# Bulk email service that handles sending an email based on time since the user signed up

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a bulk email service (like MailChimp) that lets you set up emails based on the date that the user signs up (like a weekly course) or based on a user-entered date (like a count-down to a birthday)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you want is an [email 'autoresponder'](http://www.google.com/search?q=autoresponder).  Most of the SaaS email programs have them.

- Mailchimp: http://www.mailchimp.com/features/autoresponders/
- Aweber: http://www.aweber.com/autoresponders.htm
- GetResponse: http://www.getresponse.com/features#followUpMessages
- Constant Contact: http://www.constantcontact.com/email-marketing/features/index.jsp

Features will differ from provider to provider. The right choice for you depends on your particular needs.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that that is what autoresponder was!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Bulk Mail Master](http://www.bulkmailmaster.com) for scheduled emails. Its easy and free at the moment for up to 5000 messages.